# What determines how many catapults spawn in a lane?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Once the fort and keep are down in a lane, catapults begin to spawn with minion waves.  At first, it's just one catapult.  But on really long games, I've seen waves with two or three catapults.

What determines how many catapults spawn in a lane?  Is it based on the number of enemy keeps destroyed?  Is it based on time since the keep was destroyed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only 1 catapult spawns per wave. In these late games, you've probably seen catapults that were left behind when they were fighting something else and got caught up with a different wave.

The catapults have a MUCH longer range than any other minion, so they often attack other heroes or merc camps. They also survive a lot longer because they can attack through a fort wall, thus, surviving.